# Turn LED on/off with c++

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, c++

I'm trying to write a C++ code to switch LED on when the pi receives input "1" from the user and off when it receives "2". can any one help me with such code??

Comment: Post your current code and explain what is not working.

Comment: What do you mean "from the user"? From the keyboard?

Comment: @MarkSmith yes, from the key board.

Answer (score 0):

There is a c++ library called

```
Wiringpi
```

For accessing the gpio pins. It is having documentation also.